# Method supportsFileAttributeView(...) of java's Filestore class

Tags: java, mount

I try to add support for UserDefinedFileAttributeView on my environment. This is what I've done so far. I've added 'user_xattr' option to /etc/fstab file:

```
# / was on /dev/sda3 during installation
UUID=9b1809de-d409-47ce-aee0-dd1e878b0bab /               ext4    errors=remount-ro,user_xattr  0       1
# /boot was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=fd898890-17a0-423a-987e-9dc0a5008320 /boot           ext2    defaults        0       2
# /home was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=439ea035-cac4-4801-9023-b1b1abb4ab9e /home           ext4    defaults,user_xattr        0       2
# swap was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=a534b1c7-1a00-488f-92a8-a530b5d902ac none            swap    sw              0       0
```

A simple code like this:

```
for (FileStore store : fileSystem.getFileStores()) {
  boolean supported = store.supportsFileAttributeView(UserDefinedFileAttributeView.class);
  System.out.println(store.name() + " --- " + supported);
}
```

Shows for '/home' (/dev/sdar5) is shows:

```
/dev/sda5 --- true
```

But if I do it like this:

```
FileStore store1 = Files.getFileStore((new File("/home")).toPath());
boolean supported1 = store1.supportsFileAttributeView(UserDefinedFileAttributeView.class);
System.out.println(store1.name() + " --- " + supported1);
```

I get:

```
/dev/sda5 --- false
```

Why is that? I considered to get 'true' in both cases.
My OS is Linux Mint 17.2 Rafaela 64-bit.

Comment: What version of Java are you using?

Comment: @VGR I use Java 1.8.0_65

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out, that since method supportsFileAttributeView(UserDefinedFileAttributeView.class) returns false, UserDefinedFileAttributeView is actually supported (can be used, set, retrieved...).